# Bokeh Error when making simple widget in Python

Tags: python, widget, bokeh, google-colaboratory, importerror

I keep getting this ImportError for just trying to set up a basic widget slider. Below is the input and error message.

```
import bokeh
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
import bokeh.models.widgets
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider

slider = Slider(start = 0, end = 10 , value = 1, step=.1, title = 'do nothing')

show(slider)
```

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-2c4894dccaf0> in <module>()
     10 slider = Slider(start = 0, end = 10 , value = 1, step=.1, title = 'do nothing')
     11 
---> 12 show(slider)

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py in <module>()
     79 import types
     80 
---> 81 from tornado.concurrent import (
     82     Future,
     83     is_future,

ImportError: cannot import name 'future_set_exc_info'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

I do have bokeh package installed as well. Not sure what the issue is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have an incompatible version of tornado installed. What are the versions of both Bokeh and Tornado in your environment?

Comment: @bigreddot I am not sure about bokeh, but the tornado version is 4.5.3. How would I install the correct version of tornado?

Comment: That's definitely too old. Any recent Bokeh requires Tornado version 5.1 or greater. How to upgrade depends on your situation, if you are using pip, or conda, or a system package manager.

Comment: @bigreddot got it, thank you!

Comment: Please self-answer and accept (I a happy to up-vote) so that the question is recorded as answered!

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the error above, the tornado package must be up to date. To see what version works, simply look up the package itself to see what is the current version. Then input the following code at the beginning of your program to update the package.

```
# update tornado package 
!pip install tornado==6.0.4
import tornado
```